# SQL Server - How to remove pairs of rows that sum to zero

Tags: sql-server

I need to eliminate pairs of rows from a table where the Amount nets off to zero. The netting off should only occur within a key combination of BookCode and ISIN.

Here is the original table:

```
BookCode    ISIN    Reference     Amount
ABCD        111     R1            -30
ABCD        111     R2             30
ABCD        222     R3            -25
ABCD        222     R4            -25
ABCD        222     R5            -25
ABCD        222     R6            -25
ABCD        222     R7             25
EFGH        333     R8            -20
EFGH        333     R9            -20
EFGH        444     R10            40
EFGH        444     R11           -40
IJKL        555     R12           -10
```

And this is what I would like to be left with....

```
ABCD        222     R3            -25
ABCD        222     R4            -25
ABCD        222     R5            -25
IJKL        555     R12           -10
```

In the case of

```
ABCD / 222
```

it doesn't matter which of the -25 rows pair off with the positive value of R7.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: Does your table have a primary key or a unique constraint? If no, why not?

Comment: Larnu - the reference does not have to be ordered. I just added it to demonstrate that each row has a unique reference. In 'real life' this reference number is a varchar of 16 characters, the first 3 are letters, the rest are numbers...

Comment: Smor - adding the reference number to the key effectively makes the record unique. But I as I said I need to perform the netting off just within the BookCode / ISIN combination.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that just as your comment came up, @JonnyH ; the example data mislead me. An example where 2 non-consecutive rows "netted each other off", would have been nice. :)

Comment: Larnu - fair point - sorry about that!

Comment: For the BookCode `EFGH`, and ISIN `333` there are two rows, and the amount for each is -20, so the net is -40. Why is this not in your expected results?

Comment: GarethD - Yes, sorry, that was a typo. One of the -20 rows should have read 20. But the principal of the question remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `NOT EXISTS` and `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T;
CREATE TABLE #T (BookCode VARCHAR(4), ISIN INT, Reference VARCHAR(3), Amount INT);
INSERT INTO #T (BookCode, ISIN, Reference, Amount)
VALUES
    ('ABCD', 111, 'R1', -30),
    ('ABCD', 111, 'R2', 30),
    ('ABCD', 222, 'R3', -25),
    ('ABCD', 222, 'R4', -25),
    ('ABCD', 222, 'R5', -25),
    ('ABCD', 222, 'R6', -25),
    ('ABCD', 222, 'R7', 25),
    ('EFGH', 333, 'R8', -20),
    ('EFGH', 333, 'R9', -20),
    ('EFGH', 444, 'R10', 40),
    ('EFGH', 444, 'R11', -40),
    ('IJKL', 555, 'R12', -10);


WITH RankedData AS
(   SELECT  *, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BookCode, ISIN, Amount ORDER BY Reference DESC)
    FROM    #T
)
SELECT  BookCode, ISIN, Reference, Amount
FROM    RankedData AS rd
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    RankedData AS rd2
            WHERE   rd2.BookCode = rd.BookCode
            AND     rd2.ISIN = rd.ISIN
            AND     rd2.Amount = -rd.Amount
            AND     rd2.RowNumber = rd.RowNumber
        );
```

**Output**

```
BookCode    ISIN    Reference   Amount  
------------------------------------------------
ABCD        222     R5          -25     
ABCD        222     R4          -25     
ABCD        222     R3          -25     
EFGH        333     R9          -20     
EFGH        333     R8          -20     
IJKL        555     R12         -10
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function ensures that each row can only be used to cancel off one other row, without this you would end up with no records for `ABCD` in your results.

Or if you are looking to actually delete the netted off records, rather than just select the remaining, you would use:

```
WITH RankedData AS
(   SELECT  *, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BookCode, ISIN, Amount ORDER BY Reference DESC)
    FROM    #T
)
DELETE  rd
FROM    RankedData AS rd
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    RankedData AS rd2
            WHERE   rd2.BookCode = rd.BookCode
            AND     rd2.ISIN = rd.ISIN
            AND     rd2.Amount = -rd.Amount
            AND     rd2.RowNumber = rd.RowNumber
        );

SELECT  *
FROM    #T;
```

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like the following, I forced a unique key onto it with row_number, so I'm not sure if it will work or not, but it seems to be the principle you need

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY BookCode) as id, * FROM OrigTab)
DELETE CTE WHERE CTE.id IN 
    (SELECT c1.id FROM 
                    CTE c1 
                    JOIN 
                    CTE c2 
                    ON 
                            c1.bookcode = c2.bookcode and 
                            c1.id != c2.id and 
                            c1.ISIN = c2.ISIN and 
                            c1.amount+c2.amount = 0
    )
```

or to see the rows only

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY BookCode) as id, * FROM OrigTab)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE CTE.id NOT IN 
    (SELECT c1.id FROM 
                    CTE c1 
                    JOIN 
                    CTE c2 
                    ON 
                            c1.bookcode = c2.bookcode and 
                            c1.id != c2.id and 
                            c1.ISIN = c2.ISIN and 
                            c1.amount+c2.amount = 0
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Cato. I will try this out.

Comment: that does actually DELETE the rows - if you only want to not dispaly them - hold on I'll post code

Comment: it was an interesting question - I hope the answers here aid you

Comment: So how did I come by the question in the first place? Well the example data I described is actually the result of a UNION ALL of 2 queries on the same table, where the 1st Select retrieves all rows where a Column called 'Start Date' = a particular value (a prompt in Business Objects), and the 2nd Select retrieves all rows where another column called 'Maturity Date' also equals the same value in the prompt.

Comment: The only way to distinguish the 2 sets of data was to apply a negative value to those rows retrieved from the 'Start Date' selection. Then the intention was to net off the positive and negatives, as I've described.

Comment: So now I'm looking to apply the solution you've given above to the 'UNION ALL' selections.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `PARTITION BY` and `Common Table Expressions`.

This is an example:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE 
(
    BookCode VARCHAR(10),
    ISIN     int,
    Reference  VARCHAR(10),
    Amount INT 
)

INSERT INTO @Table
(
    BookCode,
    ISIN,
    Reference,
    Amount
)
VALUES
  ('ABCD', 111, 'R1', -30)
, ('ABCD', 111, 'R2', 30)
, ('ABCD', 222, 'R3', -25)
, ('ABCD', 222, 'R4', -25)
, ('ABCD', 222, 'R5', -25)
, ('ABCD', 222, 'R6', -25)
, ('ABCD', 222, 'R7', 25)
, ('EFGH', 333, 'R8', -20)
, ('EFGH', 333, 'R9', -20)
, ('EFGH', 444, 'R10', 40)
, ('EFGH', 444, 'R11', -40)
, ('IJKL', 555, 'R12', -10)
```

And a query:

```
;WITH ordered AS
(
    SELECT 
      t.BookCode
    , t.ISIN
    , t.Reference
    , t.Amount
    , ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY t.BookCode, t.ISIN ORDER BY t.Reference) RN
    FROM  @Table t
), Pairs AS (
    SELECT 
       o1.Reference c1
    , o2.Reference c2
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  o1.Reference ORDER BY o1.Reference) RN
    FROM ordered o1
    INNER JOIN ordered o2       
        ON o1.Amount = -o2.Amount
            AND o1.RN = o1.RN
    WHERE o1.Amount > 0 
)


DELETE FROM t FROM @Table t
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM Pairs p WHERE (p.c1 = t.Reference OR p.c2 = t.Reference AND p.RN = 1)
)
SELECT * FROM @Table t
```

OUTPUT:

```
BookCode    ISIN    Reference   Amount
  ABCD       222       R4        -25
  ABCD       222       R5        -25
  ABCD       222       R6        -25
  EFGH       333       R8        -20
  EFGH       333       R9        -20
  IJKL       555       R12       -10
```

Comment: StepUp - Thanks I will try this out.